Possible limits of subsequences in the ratio test
Let $0<y_{n}$ be a sequence such that $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}\to C$
for some $0<C<\infty.$ Let $x_{k}=y_{n_{k}}$ be a subsequence of
$y_{n}$ such that $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_{k}}\to B,$ for some $0\leq B\leq\infty.$
What are the possible values for $B$ as you chose different subsequence
$y_{n_{k}}$?
My feeble attempt: Since $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}\to C,$ very roughly (the proof of the ratio
test shows) $y_{n}\approx a\cdot C^{n},$ for some $0<a$ and large
$n,$ so $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_{k}}\approx C^{n_{k+1}-n_{k}},$ for large
$k.$ Hence, it appears the set of $B$'s equals the set $\left\{ 0,C,C^{2},C^{3},\ldots\right\},$
when $C<1,$ the set $\left\{ 1\right\},$ when $C=1,$ and the set
$\left\{ C,C^{2},C^{3},\ldots,\infty\right\},$ when $C>1.$
There is no reason to consider the third case. Indeed, if $C>1$ and
$z_{n}:=1/y_{n},$ then $\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_{n}}\to\frac{1}{C}.$
This question was inspired by Comparison principle for order of convergence
Edit: This is not as simple as my original question might have implied. Let $p$ be a real number and let $y_{n}:=\tfrac{1}{n^{p}}$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots.$
Then $\tfrac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}=\left(\tfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{p}\to1.$
Let $m>1$ be an integer and let $n_{k}:=m^{k-1},$ then
$$
\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_{k}}=\left(\frac{m^{k-1}}{m^{k}}\right)^{p}=\frac{1}{m^{p}}.
$$
Hence, $C=1$ and the set $B$ contains all the values $\tfrac{1}{m^{p}},$
$m=2,3,4,\ldots.$

$C \neq 0$.  How can a power of $C$ be zero?  So how is zero in the set of possible $B$s?

@Eric Towers If $C<1$ and $m_k:=n_{k+1} - n_k\to \infty,$ then $C^{m_k}\to0.$

Of possible interest is that the ratio test can be VERY inconclusive and yet the series can still converge. The ratio test for convergence of series by Lennes (1939) gives an example where $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}$ converges and yet the subsequence limit points of the sequence $;\left{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right}_{n=1}^{\infty};$ of ratios is every extended real number in the interval $[0, \infty].$

@Dave L. Renfro Yes very much of interest. Also, saw you list of references for Continuity Sets, very interesting.

\begin{align*}
\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} &= \frac{y_{n_{k+1}}}{y_{n_k}}  \\
    &= \underbrace{\frac{y_{n_{k+1}}}{y_{(n_{k+1}\;)-1}} \frac{y_{(n_{k+1}\;)-1}}{y_{(n_{k+1}\;)-2}} \cdots \frac{y_{(n_k\,)+1}}{y_{n_k}}}_{n_{k+1}\; - n_k \text{ terms}}
\end{align*}
For a particular $(n_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$, construct the sequence $D = (d_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}} = (n_{k+1} - n_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$, the sequence of relevant differences.  If a difference only appears finitely many times in this sequence, it cannot be the power of $C$ in the limit of $x$s.  So, let $L = \{d \in D : d \text{ appears infinitely many times in $D$}\}$.
Either

(Case 1)  $L = \varnothing$, implying $d_k \rightarrow \infty$,
(Case 2)  $L = \{\ell\}$, implying $d_k \rightarrow \ell$,
(Case 3)  or $|L| > 1$, implying $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} d_k$ does not exist and this subsequence does not contribute a value for $B$, so we end consideration of this case.

To ensure that each possibility for $L$ is achieved by a subsequence of $y_n$, we observe

$y_{k^2}$ has $d_k = 2k+1 \rightarrow \infty$,
For $\ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1$, $y_{\ell k}$ has $d_k = \ell \rightarrow \ell$, and
(Optional aside: $y_{3k + \cos(\pi k)}$ has $d_k \in \{1,5\}$, with $\liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} d_k = 1$ and $\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} d_k = 5$.  Since these are different, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} d_k$ does not exist.)

Now we consider what is obtained as we range over all subsequences in each surviving case:
For Case 1, $$ B = \begin{cases}
0  ,&  0<C<1  \\
1  ,&  C = 1  \\
\infty  ,&  1<C<\infty
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$
For Case 2, we have given a subseqence for $\ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1$ such that $ B = C^\ell$.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
B &\in \begin{cases}
\{0\} \cup \{C^\ell \mid \ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1\}  ,&  0 < C < 1  \\
\{1\} \cup \{C^\ell \mid \ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1\}  ,&  C = 1  \\
\{C^\ell \mid \ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1\} \cup \{\infty\}  ,&  1 < C < \infty
\end{cases}  \\
&= \begin{cases}
\{0\} \cup \{C^\ell \mid \ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1\}  ,&  0 < C < 1  \\
\{1\}  ,&  C = 1  \\
\{C^\ell \mid \ell \in \Bbb{Z}, \ell \geq 1\} \cup \{\infty\}  ,&  1 < C < \infty
\end{cases}
\text{.}
\end{align*}
[For calculus students: $\infty$ is not a value, so you don't get to include it in "$B = \{ \dots \infty, 1<C<\infty$" or "$B \in \{ \dots \{\infty\}, 1<C<\infty$" for the calculus version of this answer.]

The proof of the ratio test (really just the definition of $y_{n+1}/y_{n} \to C$) shows given any two constants $C_{-} < C <C_{+}$ there is an $N$, such that  $y_N , C_{-}^{n-N} < y_{n+1} < y_N , C_{+}^{n-N}$ for all $n>N$. I abbreviated this as $y_n$ is approximately equal to $a , C^n$ for large $N.$
